# RecyclerView.Adapter notifyDataSetChanged not working with AsyncTask Callback

Tags: callback, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I am sure it's just a simple fault, but I'm not able to solve it.
My RecyclerView.Adapter loads its data with help of an AsyncTask (LoadAllPersonsFromDb) out of a SQLite DB. The response is handled by a callback interface (ILoadPersonFromDb.onFindAll).

Here is the code of the Adapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListViewViewholder> implements LoadAllPersonsFromDb.ILoadPersonFromDb {

private int layout;
private List<Person> persons;
private Context context;
private AdapterDataSetListener adapterDataSetListener;

public ListViewAdapter(int layout, Context context,
                       AdapterDataSetListener adapterDataSetListener) {
    this.layout = layout;
    persons = new ArrayList<>();
    this.context = context;
    this.adapterDataSetListener = adapterDataSetListener;
    new LoadAllPersonsFromDb(context, this).execute();
}

@Override
public ListViewViewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);
    return new ListViewViewholder(view, context);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ListViewViewholder holder, int position) {
    holder.assignData(persons.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return persons.size();
}

@Override
public void onFindAll(List<Person> persons) {
    Log.d("LISTVIEW", "Counted: " + persons.size() + " elements in db");
    if (this.persons != null) {
        this.persons.clear();
        this.persons.addAll(persons);
    } else {
        this.persons = persons;
    }
    adapterDataSetListener.onChangeDataSet();
    //notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public interface AdapterDataSetListener {
    void onChangeDataSet();
}
```

}

As you can see, I tried more than one way to get it running. The simple notifyDataSetChanged did not do anything, so I made another interface which is used to delegate the ui information to the relating fragment. Following code documents this interface which is implemented in the relating fragment:

```
@Override
public void onChangeDataSet() {
    Log.d("Callback", "called");
    listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    /*
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    */
}
```

Here I also tried to put it on the MainUiThread but nothing works. I'm just not able to see where my problem is. Hopefully any of you guys can give me a hint.

The logging works, which is the prove for the working callbacks.

Thank you in advance.

PS: If you need any more code, just tell me and I will provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tell the background, I used RecyclerView in Version 23.1.1 because the latest 23.2.0 had some weird behaviour in holding a huge space for each card. 
//Update: the problem with the space between cards, was because of a failure of myself in the layout file (*match_parent instead of wrap_content*). -_-

The upshot was using the latest version again and everything worked just fine. I have no idea why, but at the moment I am just happy, that I can go on. This little problem wasted enough time.

Maybe somebody has a similar situation and can use this insight.

Thx anyway @yUdoDis.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the interface-llistener pattern, try this

```
@Override
public void onFindAll(List<Person> persons) {
    Log.d("LISTVIEW", "Counted: " + persons.size() + " elements in db");
    if (this.persons != null) {
        this.persons.clear();
        this.persons.addAll(persons);
    } else {
        this.persons = persons;
    }
    refereshAdapter(persons);
}

public void refereshAdapter(List<Person> persons){
        listViewAdapter.clear();
        listViewAdapter.addAll(persons);
        listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```